# Why is my program giving a totally different output when I compile with mingw as compared to g++

Tags: c++, g++, mingw

So when i compile this code (using the mersenne twister found here: http://www-personal.umich.edu/~wagnerr/MersenneTwister.html ):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "mtrand.h"

using namespace std;
double pythag(double x, double y) {
    double derp=0;
    derp=(x*x)+(y*y);
    derp=sqrt(derp);
}

int main() {
    double x=0;
    double y=0;
    double pi=0;
    double hold1=0;

    double hold2=0;
    double hits=0;
    MTRand mt;
    mt.seed();
   // cout.precision(10);
    for(long i=1; i<=100000000000l; i++) {
        x=abs(mt.rand());
        y=abs(mt.rand());
        if(pythag(x,y)<=1) {
            hits++;
        }
        if(i%100000l==0) {
            pi=(4*hits)/i;
            cout << "\r" << i << "   " << pi ;
        }
    }
    cout  <<"\n";
    return 42;
}
```

Using g++ ("g++ pi.cc -o pi")
And run the resulting application, I get the output i wanted, a running tally of pi calculated using the Monte Carlo method.
But, when i compile with mingw g++ ("i686-pc-mingw32-g++ -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc pi.cc -o pi.exe")
I always get a running tally of 0.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Undefined behavior is what you are looking for. Turn the warning level up "-Wall" and fix the compilation warnings. Warnings are really logical errors in your code.

Comment: `pythag` says it returns a double, and yet has no return statement.

Comment: thanks, my bad on this one, can't believe i overlooked that

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's because you omitted the return statement:

```
double pythag(double x, double y) {
    double derp=0;
    derp=(x*x)+(y*y);
    derp=sqrt(derp);

    //  You're missing this!!!
    return derp;

}
```

I'd be surprised that you didn't get any warnings or errors on this.

Answer (score 0):

pythag() does not return anything, as Loki is trying to say without telling you the exact answer. That means the return value is not specified.

Why do you return 42 in main()?! 8-)

Comment: Derp, had accidently reverted to a previous version of my code and didn't realize it, works perfectly now. Had to return something, why not 42?

Comment: @natman3400: Actually main() is special you do not need to return anything (no return is equivalent to return 0). The value returned is an indication to the OS on the success/failure of the application. A return value of 0 indicates success. A return value of anything else indicates failure.

Comment: I had always been taught that I had to return something, most likely because I learned on picky compiliers .I am aware of that convention, but the reason I use 42 is because in my hello world way back when, my compsci teacher instructed us to put in 42, so i have used that as the goto value by instinct ever since.

Comment: @natma3400: it's more than a convention. Is what whatever system manager expect from a program that terminated its run. 

The return value is the answer you give to the process that called your main() function. It must respect the "contract" subtended in its call. your return value .... does not belong to you!

Comment: Unless you encounter an error, you are expected to return 0 unless very specifically defined somewhere (i.e. "contract" as mentioned by Emilio.) Zero is important because shell scripts rely on it to assume that the process succeeded. So 42 looks funny to me 8-) Weird teacher.